# PWM Low-pass filter for LCD contrast pin with a potentiometer?

Tags: pwm, switching, lcd, dac, low-pass

As a software developer, electronic engineering isn't my strong suit, so I'm struggling to understand some simple concepts regarding this circuit.

This is a unique circuit I have encountered that is used to control the contrast pin (`Vo`) of 16x2 LCDs, and I'd like to understand how it works.

[image: LCD control contrast using PWM low-pass Arduino]

The other methods I've seen online doesn't utilize a transistor, or involve a potentiometer when the contrast pin is being controlled by the PWM pin.

For reference, the PWM frequency is **490 Hz**, and the operating voltage (`VCC`) is **5V**.

Could you please shed some light regarding the purpose of **POT1** and **Q5** here?  Can I assume that this circuit will operate as intended, or could there be any shortsights in its design?

Answer (score 1):

What it does is the PWM turns the transistor on and off. When on, it pulls current from capacitor and the pot and R62 define the low target voltage. When off, both resistors and the pot charges the capacitor with curren toward the target voltage of 5V VCC.

So when driven with PWM, the duty cycle (and frequency) define the contrast pin average DC voltage, as it is filtered by the capacitor.

The role of pot must be some kind of calibration or adjustment of the proper range for contrast voltage.

I don't know if you can assume the circuit works as intended. Some displays have recommendation that there should be no capacitor on the contrast pin, because if the supply voltage is turned off, they may not tolerate voltages outside VCC on contrast pin.

In reality, the contrast pin is the low drive voltage for the LCD glass, and the drive voltage is determined by difference of VCC pin voltage minus contrast pin voltage.

Comment: Thank you, so what I'm getting from this is that the contrast pin doesn't necessarily map `0V`-`5V` to 0%-100% of the contrast, but somewhere in between. Also, when the transistor is on, the other pin of the capacitor seems to be shorted to the ground -- will this take too much current to discharge the cap?

Comment: Also, is the reason for the recommendation about the retained charge in the cap when the power supply is cut off? In other words, VCC is floating, while Vo has the same voltage level as the last moment the cap was powered.

Comment: The cap is not necessarily shorted, there is the pot which can be set in any position. And when supply is disconnected, VCC may not float, as you have loads it will drop to 0V, i.e. GND level. If contrast pin has voltage, it may discharge through unintended paths, degrade something or damage something.